# TextBox - Object Reference Not Set To An Instance of an Object

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a very simple piece of code that is throwing an unexpected error and I am struggling to understand what could possibly be wrong.

```
private void dataNames_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{   
    DataGridViewRow row = dataNames.CurrentCell.OwningRow;
    string val = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
    txtName.Text = val;
}
```

The Object dataNames is a DataGridView with only a single Column in it called Names.

When I double click a Name from the Grid I want it to populate the Textbox (txtName)

I fail to see how a Textbox can produce an 'Object not set . . ' error when all I am doing is posting a value to its Text property.  When I step through the string 'val' does pick up the correct value from the DataGridView.

Comment: Your code suggests the column is "Name" but your description suggests it is "Names"

Comment: Where  "txtName" textbox is exactly located ? Inside the grid or outside the grid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, having spent a good while unable to find the problem, I go and spot it straight after posting the question.

The error is earlier in the Form_Load event, which calls a custom ClearForm method, which blanks all text fields on the form.  However I had done the following :-

```
txtTitle.Text = null;
txtAge.Text = null;
txtName = null;
```

Hence I set the textbox itself = null, rather than its text property.

Sometimes the simplest of typos produces the most puzzling of errors!