# Text box Control not getting initialized inside UserControl(.ascx page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webusercontrols

I have textbox inside a user control(ascx page) like this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" PlaceHolder="Practice Name"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now when I try to access this textbox from code behind, it is not getting initialized and shows as **null.**

```
textbox1.text = "ABC";
```

The above statement should assign textbox1's text as "ABC" but it is showing as null and gives an error **object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20882549/8736208
u need to search better before open a new issue.

Comment: @Er.Er the link you have provided does not solve my problem. I have not made it null anywhere in my code. I just want to access it and have some value in it. And also it is not in normal (aspx page), this text box is in user control (ascx page).

Comment: Where is `textbox1.text = "ABC";`?

Comment: @wazz it is in Page_Load event of User Control page(.ascx).

Comment: This might not do anything but is 'text' with a capital T? Try `textbox1.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your user control is registered on the aspx page that's using it. At the top should be something like

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/MyCtrl.ascx" TagName="MyCtrl" TagPrefix="xyz" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create another textbox drag and drop .. Place holder could make some issue in implementing asp controls.